# Multiple accounts heroku keys mixed up

Tags: heroku, ssh, ssh-keys, heroku-toolbelt

I have multiple accounts on heroku and I think my ssh keys got messed up but I have no idea how to fix it. 
When i try 'git push heroku master' i get the error 'your account ***** does not have access to *****'

How do I fix my keys so that I can push to heroku?

Comment: A simple search will lead you to the heroku SSH documentation. Stackoverflow has no way of knowing exactly what needs to be corrected in your personal setup. What exactly are you hoping for here?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku wont allow to share ssh key between 2 heroku accounts.

I will help you to get through this by a hacky fix

1.First go to .ssh/ directory in your home folder

2.Move all the files and keep it in any other folder(Don't delete it)

3.Open the terminal and Login  to heroku using "heroku login" command and login to your heroku account which you want to push now.

4.After sucessfully logging in to your account enter "heroku keys:add" command. it will create a new ssh keys for your account. you can now push to your account easily.

Suppose if you want to push to any application using your old account replace the .ssh/ folder files to backuped files. (Backup your current .ssh/ to any folder)
or you can repeat same step 1-4 for that account.

I hope this will solve your problem.